# How to define large amounts of variables correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, constants, global

I've got about 30 variables hard-coded into a php script and I need to remove them all and put them into their own places. I'm wondering, should define them as constants, globals, put them into a class, throw them in a separate file, or something else.

Also, I'm curious on how to define an array of constants.

So, what do you think the correct way is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this, if what you're trying to do is "define an array of constants".

```
$constantsToDefine = array(
  'PORT' => 80,
  'NUMBER_OF_LEGS' => 10
);
foreach ($constantsToDefine as $key => $value) {
  define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

constant is not a bad idea as it does not get overridden

or you can consider [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: if you use parse_ini_file, do not forget to use a cache mecanism for the results (like Zend_Cache_Frontend_File). Parsing a file at each request is not no fastest way of setting constants.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what they are, what they represent, and what they mean. Your question is too vague.

You cannot define an array of constants, or a constant that is an array.

Comment: you can define array of configure variables. like $conf['variable_name'] , etc...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Possibly so, though I did answer part of the question in the array of constants.

Comment: You can loop over a key => value array map, defining a constant named key with value, however.

Comment: @TomR: I don't understand. Where do constants come into play with arrays? The key will be a variable, not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on what these variable represent, where they will be used, and how they will be used. Are these variable all related?

As far as defining an array of constants... one way is just to create [an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This array will not really be "Constant", though as the values can be overwritten.

```
$constArr = array(
    "companyAddress" => "123 Fake St" , 
    "companyCity" => "Queens" , 
    "companyState" => "NY" , 
    "companyActive" => true
);
```

then you can access your "constants" like this...

```
echo $constArr["companyAddress"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In several of the bigger applications we've written, we've put all of our "constant" variables into a single "include" file and then defined them using the `define` function. Then, we just include that file in all other pages.

For example, our include file would look something like:

```
define(CONSTANT_ONE, 1);
define(CONSTANT_TWO, TRUE);
```

Then, we would `require_once('includes.php');` at the top of our other scripts.

Obviously the advantage to placing them all in a single file is centralized control.